# In Excel, how to separate memory resources

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I verify that this is actually happening if you add /x to the Excel destination?

[image]

In Task Manager, if I run the line `RUN EXCEL.EXE /x`, the Excel files are opened separately, but when I add the line to the destination of the Excel application, this does not occur.

Is it possible that you will have to wait a few minutes?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say "to the destination of the Excel application". Do you mean that when you modify a Shortcut you use to open Excel, that argument is not followed, or something else? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: This may be more accurately titled "How to launch Excel as a separate process instance from a shortcut (using /x switch), instead of a separate sheet in an existing Excel process".